# OpenStack Swift Multi Part Upload jclouds

Tags: java, upload, openstack-swift, jclouds

I'm using jclouds Java SDK to interact with the OpenStack resources, I want to upload as multipart yet I didn't find in the SDK how to do that, in the examples I only saw a way to upload multipart but just for the blobs, which is not what I'm using, but nothing for the OpenStack Swift
is there anyway to upload multipart to the Swift? 
keep in mind that I'm using the class `PutOptions` so I can generate metadata for the file
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jclouds offers two layers to work with: the portable `BlobStore` layer and the lower-level provider API.  You should use the portable layer when possible and can upload multipart via:

```
blobStore.putBlob(container, blob, new PutOptions().multipart(true));
```

If you need to use the lower-level provider API to access some other functionality, you can upload individual parts via `SwiftApi.getObjectApi.put` then create a SLO manifest via `SwiftApi.getStaticLargeObjectApi.replaceManifest`.  The [jclouds provider guide](https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/#swift) has an example of how to get `SwiftApi` from `ContextBuilder.buildApi`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I  saw that part of code, to be honest its a misunderstanding since I thought the blob store is the **Azure storage service**, so I understand its has nothing to do with Azure